# Error Notification "Design config must have area and store" in backend

Tags: error, magento-2.1.8

In the M2 backend when I am trying to enable "Front-end Builder Account" in System > All Users > a user and save it is giving me error Notification "Design config must have area and store" in the backend.

From the notification can you suggest me is there anything I missed setting up?

Answer (score 0):

Errors come from the below file

> Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder

In the above file have a line

```
protected function getTemplate()
{
    return $this->templateFactory->get($this->templateIdentifier, $this->templateModel)
        ->setVars($this->templateVars)
        ->setOptions($this->templateOptions);
}
```

I have checked that

**$this->templateOptions** contain below data

```
Array{
    [area] => frontend,
    [store] =>
}
```

When we specify store than it resolves the error.

please if this help than this post needs to be appreciated.

Thank you